# How to join a strings in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file containing websites

```
whatsmyip
stackoverflow
```

and I want to join each line with `.com` at the end of each site. What is the best way to accomplish this? 
I set a variable called $sites and on that variable I called the .txt file into the script with `get-content` I tried doing a foreach loop to join the two text but my syntax isn't working. Any suggestions?.

```
foreach ( $website in $site  ) {
 $website -join ".com"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `"$website.com"` to create the string.